# vscode wont run nvm packages without me rerunning the .zsh_profile command everytime i restart vscode

Tags: javascript, npm, visual-studio-code, nvm, npx

I know a lot of other people have had this issue but i cant seem to make it work.

if i dont run these commands in the vscode terminal everytime i open it it wont run npx,npm or nvm.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

i also added these commands to my .zsh_profile and added `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": "-L",` to my settings.json folder inside Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json

i restarted vscode and npm,nvm,npx still wont run.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adxg3.png)

after that i switched terminal profiles in vscode back to bash and it works to my surprise but other commands like `ls` `find` wont work and gives me a weird error so i cant use the bash in my vscode terminal even if i wanted to.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4X03.png)

any suggestions on what should i do next?

Comment: Try moving the lines to `.zshenv`, which is sourced in every shell. The `-L` parameter is not needed anymore then. Does that make a difference? See for reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout

Comment: if theres no `.zshenv` file in my home folder should i create it. or is it a file that should already exist somewhere else like  the `settings.json` file?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, create it in your home directory.

Comment: @carlfriedrich that solves the problem, thank you.  you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the lines to `.zshenv` in your home directory. This is [the place for pre-defined environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71258/317320), it is implicitly sourced in every shell. Create the file if it does not exist.

The `-L` parameter is not needed anymore then.